# Set up a MSVC DLL to be ABI-compatible to a __stdcall MinGW DLL

Tags: visual-c++, dll, mingw, dllexport

I'm part of a team reviving a dormant open source project. One of the first things I did was fix the software to build with Visual C++ on Windows. The plan is to distribute the MSVC version in the upcoming release.

The current DLL is built with the `__stdcall` calling convention, for reasons I can't explain. No big deal, except it was also built with MinGW and MinGW and Visual C++ disagree about what `__stdcall` means. See [here](http://wyw.dcweb.cn/stdcall.htm) for details, but basically MinGW mangles the name like `Function@n` and MSVC mangles it like `_Function@n`. It's a good reason not to use `__stdcall` in your DLLs...

The switch to `__stdcall` was important enough to the previous maintainers that they bumped a major version number (because it broke ABI compatibility) when they switched to it and I'm reluctant to bump it again to switch back to `__cdecl`.

Basically, I need to convince MSVC to decorate the symbols in the DLL like MinGW does, either with some sort of alias, or just changing the name. I don't care which, as the other software in the suite can be easily rebuilt to call the DLL however is needed - it's existing software I'm worried about.

I suspect I need a .DEF file for this, but I'm reluctant to make one by hand. There's dozens of exported functions.

So here's the question - is there any automated or mostly-automated way to do this?

Comment: No.  Only a .def file can rename exports.  The actual exported name should never matter when you create an import library.

Comment: That's what I thought. I'm trying to make that .DEF file automatically, or at least mostly automatically. My problem is that I'm trying to provide a DLL that will work with existing code that already linked against the import library for the previous version.

Comment: So link it with the new import library.  This is the point of an import library.

Comment: I am trying to provide a library that will work with existing applications that users already use with the old DLL, and that I don't control and can not change. Or are you saying I can somehow do that with the new import library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to write a simple Python script to do this. I don't know if there's an easier way, but this works for me

You'll want [pexports](http://wyw.dcweb.cn/download.asp?path=&file=pexports-0.43.zip) (linked from [here](http://wyw.dcweb.cn/stdcall.htm)), and you can run it on your DLL with `pexports mylib.dll > mylib-stock.def`. Then run this Python script with `fixdefs.py mylib-stock.def mylib.def` and include that while building the library. Seems to work fine. You'll get a file like:

```
_Function@n
Function@n=_Function@n
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sys import argv

def fixline(line):
    if line.startswith('_'):
        line=line.strip()
        return "%s\n%s=%s\n" % (line, line[1:], line)
    return line

if __name__=="__main__":
    if len(argv)!=3:
        print "usage %s <input.def> <output.def>" % argv[0]
        exit(1)

    with open(argv[1], 'r') as input:
        with open(argv[2], 'w') as output:
            for line in input:
            output.write(fixline(line))
```